# How can I add two configuration dialogs for two independent non required features in Wix

Tags: configuration, dialog, wix, installation

I'm updating a setup project that had one feature with a corresponding configuration dialog for that feature.
Now I need to add one more feature with its own configuration dialog to the setup project and, when the user chooses the feature1 display feature1's configuration dialog, when the user chooses feature2 display feature2's configuration dialog and when the user chooses both features display the feature1's then feature2's configuration dialogs in a sequence. Obviously if the user chooses none, setup program can't continue because it has no features to install. That last rule is not reflected here in the project yet.
This is the last UI snippet from the project.

Sample Features are **Translator** and **Cache** in and sample dialogs are **TransParams** and **CacheParams** respectively

```
<UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo"/>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText"/>

  <DialogRef Id="TransParams"/>
  <DialogRef Id="CacheParams"/>

  <!-- skip license dialog-->
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

  <!-- Translator parameters -->
  <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="CompleteButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="TransParams">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="TransParams"><![CDATA[&Translator = "3"]]></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CacheParams"><![CDATA[&Translator <> "3" AND &Cache = "3"]]></Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="TransParams" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg" Order="1">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallComplete"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="TransParams" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="1">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="TransParams" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CacheParams" Order="1">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallComplete"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="TransParams" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CacheParams" Order="1"><![CDATA[WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom" AND &Cache = "3"]]></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="TransParams" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2"><![CDATA[WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom"]]></Publish>

  <!-- Cache parameters -->
  <Publish Dialog="CacheParams" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallComplete"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="CacheParams" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="TransParams"><![CDATA[WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom" AND &Translator = 3]]></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="CacheParams" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg"><![CDATA[WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallCustom" AND &Translator <> 3]]></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="CacheParams" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>

</UI>
```

I tried several other combinations and none of them helped me much more.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The id's for the next button in the custom dialog, need to match the actual ids of the target dialogs.
Change "SymTransParams" to "TransParams", and "VolCacheParams" to "CacheParams".
Also, the syntax of "&Translator = 3" should be "!<[CDATA[&Translator = 3]]>"

For the case when no features are choosen, you might decide to disable the Next button.
 In the definition of the "CustomizeDlg" section/file, change the definition of the "Next" button to be disabled by default, and add a condition to enable it only if one of the features are chosen.

```
    <UI>
  <Dialog Id="CustomizeDlg" ....
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" Disabled="yes">
          <Condition Action="enable">!<CDATA[[&Translator = 3 OR &Cache = 3 ]]</Condition>
```

You could improve this by having a dynamic label displayed that instructed the user to pick one feature before continuing/next.

Comment: Thanks @jdh, I will try your suggestions, however, names were changed in the samples to simplify the reading so the actual ones are correct, I edited the sample to make it as you pointed out. What I need the most is the correct sequence of dialogs and I can't still make it work, if I choose one of them it works correctly but if I choose both just one configuration dialog appears. I solved that with the complete configuration which I already fixed it but not when the chosen setup type is custom. Thanks anyway for your help, I appreciate it.